# Replace parts of file with 0xFF?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, file, binary

I want to modify a file so every byte from location `0x3000` to `0xDC000` is replaced with `0xFF`, everything else should be unmodified.

How to accomplish this with standard Linux tools?

Comment: Welcome to SO, on SO we do encourage people to do add their efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problems, so please do add the same in your question and let us know then.

Comment: `yes $'\xFF' | tr -d '\n' | dd conv=notrunc bs=1c seek=$((0x3000-1)) count=$((0xDC000)) of=FILE`

Comment: Is **Perl** *"standard"*? **Python**? `xxd`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [jhnc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60408936/replace-parts-of-file-with-0xff#comment106864742_60408936) with little improvements (explained at the end of this answer).

```
#! /bin/bash
overwrite() {
    file="$1"; from="$2"; to="$3"; with="$4"
    yes '' | tr \\n "\\$(printf %o "$with")" |
    dd conv=notrunc bs=1 seek="$((from))" count="$((to-from))" of="$file"
}
```

In your case you would use the function from above like

```
overwrite yourFile 0x3000 0xDC000 0xFF
```

The start and end byte are both 0-based. The start is inclusive and the end is exclusive. Example:

```
$ printf 00000 > file
$ overwrite file 1 3 0x57
$ hexdump -C file
00000000  30 57 57 30 30   |0WW00|
00000005
```

**Improvements made:**

- Fixed wrong `count=...` and explained interpretation of start and end.
- Allow filling with null bytes.
  <sub>If you want to write null bytes `0x00` you cannot use `yes $'\x00'`. The null byte would represent the end of `yes`'s argument string making the call equivalent to `yes ''`. Since `yes '' | tr -d \\n` produces no output `dd` will wait indefinitely.

  The command presented in this answer allows you to fill the region with any byte (choose one from 0x00 to 0xFF).</sub>

Comment: Nice work. On macOS, use `dd conv=notrunc bs=1 ...` as the `c` is not accepted.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thank you for the hint. I just copied the `c` from jhnc. It is now removed as the [POSIX documentation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/dd.html) clearly states that `bs` is specified in bytes anyway.

Comment: In my defence, the question specified linux :-)  Nice generalisation. The question was ambiguous about 0- or 1-based locations and (s,e) / [s,e) / [s,e]. Good catch on the count.

Answer (score 1):

If `Perl` is your option, would you please try the following:

```
perl -e '
$start = 0x3000;                        # start position to overwrite
$end = 0xDC000;                         # end position to overwrite
$file = "file";                         # filename to modify (replace with your filename)

open(FH, "+< $file") or die "$file";    # open the file "$file" to both read & write with the filehandle "FH"
seek(FH, $start, 0);                    # jump to the start position
for ($i = $start; $i < $end; $i++) {    # loop over the overwrite area
    print FH "\xFF";                    # replace the byte with 0xFF
}
close(FH);
'
```